# Pulling amplify backend deletes react files in src

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

I created a react project using `npx create-react-app project-name`,  then I pulled my amplify backend using `amplify pull --appId X --envName staging`, then I chose options for a javascript react app and used defaults for all the other options e.g. source directory. The problem is when amplify creates it's files in src it deletes all the react files inside the folder that were generated for me. I could recreate them manually but it's a bit annoying. Is there anyway to stop amplify deleting these files? Also I tried doing it the other way round, pulling amplify and then creating the react app but I get console errors when I do so.

Comment: What version of amplify are you running? - you can check by running amplify --version

Are you inside the project-name directory when you execute amplify pull ?